# PhoneGap [Android] : Using .Mbtiles to make custom offline map

Tags: cordova, offline, android-sqlite, leaflet

I'm working on phonegap for android application : this application consists on using .mbtiles offline maps. i use Leaflet to manipulate the map.
I found an issue in extracting tiles from the Map.mbtiles.

I would be very happy , if someone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

http://giscollective.org/tutorials/web-mapping/leaflet-1/

should be useful for setting up a leaflet map, then extract your mbtiles and read

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/leaflet-js/oX31C6KcXVw

for how to reference the offline png files. I advise you extract tiles that you have made (eg from TileMill), not tiles downloaded from online for copyright reasons.

Hope that helps?